# Failing to import a file

Tags: python, python-import

I am currently trying to code a searching program, which makes use of a program I've already written. It refuses to get to the second print statement.

```py
print("Relevance: ")

# import sqlite3
import Breakdown.py as bd
import re, nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
# from sqlite3 import Error
from  autocorrect import spell

print("Input line: ")
```

The file structure looks like this:

[image]

However, I can't work out why it can't get past that import section.
This is somewhat important.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `import Breakdown as bd`, if you are in the same folder as `Breakdown.py`

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

`import Breakdown as bd`

python will import the Breakdown.py file as a module. It will be looking for any variable or function named "py" in the Breakdown module if you use:

`import Breakdown.py as bd`

... which I don't think is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `Breakdown.py` file in the path where you're starting Python or in one of the directories where Python looks for libraries:

```
import os
for p in sys.path:
   print(p)
```

and use `import Breakdown` (no .py).

Or else add to `sys.path`the folder where the module is with:

```
sys.path.append('/your/foldername')
```